# Using Ansible set_fact to create a dictionary from register results

Tags: ansible

In Ansible I've used `register` to save the results of a task in the variable `people`. Omitting the stuff I don't need, it has this structure:

```json
{
    "results": [
        {
            "item": {
                "name": "Bob"
            },
            "stdout": "male"
        },
        {
            "item": {
                "name": "Thelma"
            },
            "stdout": "female"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to use a subsequent `set_fact` task to generate a new variable with a dictionary like this:

```json
{
    "Bob": "male",
    "Thelma": "female"
}
```

I guess this might be possible but I'm going round in circles with no luck so far.

Comment: Be aware that since ansible v2.2, with_items requires explicit jinja2 wrapping. So the first sample would be:
<pre> - name: Populate genders set_fact: genders: "{{ genders|default({}) | combine( {item.item.name: item.stdout} ) }}" with_items: "{{ people.results }}"
</pre>

Answer (score 158, accepted):

I think I got there in the end.

The task is like this:

```yaml
- name: Populate genders
  set_fact:
    genders: "{{ genders|default({}) | combine( {item.item.name: item.stdout} ) }}"
  with_items: "{{ people.results }}"
```

It loops through each of the dicts (`item`) in the `people.results` array, each time creating a new dict like `{Bob: "male"}`, and `combine()`s that new dict in the `genders` array, which ends up like:

```json
{
    "Bob": "male",
    "Thelma": "female"
}
```

It assumes the keys (the `name` in this case) will be unique.

---

I then realised I actually wanted a list of dictionaries, as it seems much easier to loop through using `with_items`:

```yaml
- name: Populate genders
  set_fact:
    genders: "{{ genders|default([]) + [ {'name': item.item.name, 'gender': item.stdout} ] }}"
  with_items: "{{ people.results }}"
```

This keeps combining the existing list with a list containing a single dict. We end up with a `genders` array like this:

```json
[
    {'name': 'Bob', 'gender': 'male'},
    {'name': 'Thelma', 'gender': 'female'}
]
```

Comment: You can avoid declaring empty dictionary if you use _default_ filter.
`genders: "{{ genders | default({}) | combine( {item.item.name: item.stdout}) }}`

Comment: Thanks @smicyk - I belatedly added your handy suggestion into the examples.

Comment: Second example should be : genders: `"{{ genders|default([]) + [ {'name': item.item.name, 'gender': item.stdout} ] }}"`, with a default array instead of a default object.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierLecrivain - I fixed the example.

Comment: Anyway to do this in Ansible pre-2.0?

Answer (score 21):

Thank you Phil for your solution; in case someone ever gets in the same situation as me, here is a (more complex) variant:

```yaml
---
# this is just to avoid a call to |default on each iteration
- set_fact:
    postconf_d: {}

- name: 'get postfix default configuration'
  command: 'postconf -d'
  register: command

# the answer of the command give a list of lines such as:
# "key = value" or "key =" when the value is null
- name: 'set postfix default configuration as fact'
  set_fact:
    postconf_d: >
      {{
        postconf_d |
        combine(
          dict([ item.partition('=')[::2]|map('trim') ])
        )
  with_items: command.stdout_lines
```

This will give the following output (stripped for the example):

```js
"postconf_d": {
    "alias_database": "hash:/etc/aliases", 
    "alias_maps": "hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases",
    "allow_min_user": "no", 
    "allow_percent_hack": "yes"
}
```

Going even further, parse the lists in the 'value':

```yaml
- name: 'set postfix default configuration as fact'
  set_fact:
    postconf_d: >-
      {% set key, val = item.partition('=')[::2]|map('trim') -%}
      {% if ',' in val -%}
        {% set val = val.split(',')|map('trim')|list -%}
      {% endif -%}
      {{ postfix_default_main_cf | combine({key: val}) }}
  with_items: command.stdout_lines
...
```

```js
"postconf_d": {
    "alias_database": "hash:/etc/aliases", 
    "alias_maps": [
        "hash:/etc/aliases", 
        "nis:mail.aliases"
    ], 
    "allow_min_user": "no", 
    "allow_percent_hack": "yes"
}
```

A few things to notice:

- in this case it's needed to "trim" everything (using the `>-` in [YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/248390) and `-%}` in [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control)), otherwise you'll get an error like:

  ```
  FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got u\"  {u'...
  ```
- obviously the `{% if ..` is far from bullet-proof
- in the postfix case, `val.split(',')|map('trim')|list` could have been simplified to `val.split(', ')`, but I wanted to point out the fact you will need to `|list` otherwise you'll get an error like:

  ```
  "|combine expects dictionaries, got u\"{u'...': <generator object do_map at ...
  ```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Much tanks for the `-%}` note! I have been fighting with this for weeks.

Comment: This is a great tip! Just one note, with Ansible 2.4.3 at least every line except the last needs  `{%- ... -%}` with the dash on both the open and close bracket, otherwise the dict will be interpreted as a string

Comment: Thank you for this tip, the `>-` and `-%}` oddities would have been extremely time consuming to figure out. I owe you. Thanks.

Comment: What is the `[::2]` after `item.partition('=')`? I guess some index but I'm familiar with Python to tell.

Comment: @gadamiak: [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) split the string with the guarantee you get two items in case the delimiter is not found and the obscure [`[::2]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=slice#common-sequence-operations) syntax is a slice