# How to convert a string to dict in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to convert the simple output of python, and I tried to follow the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703650/converting-output-of-python-script-to-dict-in-ansible).
But it doesn't seem to work in my sample code. `data` is a string coming from the output of a `shell` task.

How do I make  `minio_list1['test']` legitimate?

```yaml
---
- name: data test
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    data: "test: something"

  tasks:
  - name: get the list
    set_fact:
      minio_list1: "{{ minio_list1 | default({}) | combine ( { item.split(':')[0]: item.split(':')[1] } ) }}"
    with_items:
      - data

  - name: print
    debug:
      msg: "{{ minio_list1 }}"

  - name: print
    debug:
      msg: "{{ minio_list1['test'] }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `test: something` is a valid YAML snippet, why not using the YAML capabilities of Ansible, and so the filter `from_yaml`?

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    data: "test: something"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        minio_list1: "{{ data | from_yaml }}"

    - debug:
        var: minio_list1['test'] # or minio_list1.test
```

This yields:

```
TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  minio_list1['test']: something
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wanted to remove ' ' before something.

TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "minio_list1['test']": " something"
}

Comment: @spark use an extra [`trim`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.trim) filter, then: `minio_list1['test'] | trim`