# Using a variable for the hosts in a playbook in v2.5

Tags: ansible

I have a simple playbook and I want to enter the host interactively. My code looks like:

```
- hosts: "{{my_hosts}}"

vars_prompt:
- name: "my_hosts" 
  prompt: "Enter the hosts" 
  private: no
```

This code works fine in 2.3 and 2.4, but in 2.5 I get the message below. 
I haven't seen anything in the release notes that would explain why it 
stopped working. Anyone knows why?

Thanks,

a

```
ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'scraper_hosts' is undefined

The error appears to have been in 'my-playbook.yml': line 8, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- hosts: "{{my_hosts}}"
^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they start a value. For instance:

with_items:
  - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its not intended behavior, please check [reported issue at github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37984).

Fix is on its way [according to this linked pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/38000).

Comment: Thanks. I need to start looking at those bug trackers. Maybe I should go past the first page next time I search on google.

Comment: Well, i had a similar experience with you a few weeks ago, and was advised to open an issue at github, thats how/why i got familiar with the process. [my issue if interested, it was fixed in 2.5.2 by the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983209/ansible-cannot-append-into-a-list-in-a-with-items-loop). Cheers.