# set_facts in loops (with_items) does not work as expected

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to add some items to a list in a loop. Always I get only the last item as result.

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.5.1
  config file = /home/ansible/ansible_devel/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.13 (default, Jan 11 2017, 10:56:06) [GCC]
```

To show you what my problem is I have stripped down the code to the minimum:

```
---
- hosts:
    - localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
  pre_tasks:
  tasks:

  - name: "Merge firewall variables"
    set_fact:
      my_list: |
        {%- if my_list is not defined -%}
        {%-   set tmp_my_list=[ 1 ] -%}
        {%- else -%}
        {%-   set tmp_my_list=my_list -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- set dummy=tmp_my_list.append(item) -%}
        {{ tmp_my_list }}
    with_items:
        - a
        - b
        - c

  - debug: msg="{{ my_list }}"
```

What I would expect is:

```
$ ansible-playbook test6.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Merge firewall variables] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=a)
ok: [localhost] => (item=b)
ok: [localhost] => (item=c)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        1,
        "a",
        "b", 
        "c"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

But what I get is:

```
$ ansible-playbook test6.yml 


PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Merge firewall variables] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=a)
ok: [localhost] => (item=b)
ok: [localhost] => (item=c)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        1, 
        "c"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

In older versions of ansible this code worked. Can you help me to get it running in ansible 2.5.1?
Thanks,
   Lars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a 2.5.1 specific bug, you can check more info and link to the github issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983209/ansible-cannot-append-into-a-list-in-a-with-items-loop).

Upgrading to ansible 2.5.2 will help you get rid of it, it was resolved.