# Ansible create list with 'with_items'

Tags: ansible

I want to create a new list through a loop. I created a task like this. Ansible 2.9.10

```
- name: "Generate list"
  set_fact:
    dst: "{{dst_list | default([])}} + [ '{{ item[0] }}' ]" 
  with_items:
    - "{{failed_connections}}"
- debug: var=dst


"failed_connections": [
    [
        "1.1.1.1", 
        8888
    ], 
    [
        "1.1.1.1", 
        8080
    ], 
    [
        "2.2.2.2", 
        8888
    ], 
    [
        "2.2.2.2", 
        8080
    ], 
    [
        "2.2.2.2", 
        443
    ]
]
```

I end up only getting the last item in the list.

```
TASK [access-consul-kv : Generate list] 

*********************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'1.1.1.1', 8888])
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'1.1.1.1', 8080])
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'2.2.2.2', 8888])
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'2.2.2.2', 8080])
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'2.2.2.2', 443])

TASK [access-consul-kv : debug] *****************************************************************************************************ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "dst": [
        "2.2.2.2"
    ]
}
```

How can I get a list of all addresses and preferably only unique ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your task:

```
- name: "Generate list"
  set_fact:
    dst: "{{dst_list | default([])}} + [ '{{ item[0] }}' ]" 
  with_items:
    - "{{failed_connections}}"
```

You're setting `dst` to the value of `dst_list` + some value. Since you never define `dst_list`, you always get the value from the `default([])` expression, so your `set_fact` task actually looks like this:

```
set_fact:
  dst: [ '{{ item[0] }}' ]
```

If you want to append to a list, you need to use the name of the variable you're setting with `set_fact` inside the `set_fact` expression, like this:

```
set_fact:
  dst: "{{ dst|default([]) + [ item[0] ] }}"
```

Note that we only need one set of `{{...}}` markers here.

I will often avoid the use of the `default` filter by using a `vars` key to set the default value, like this:

```
- name: "Generate list"
  set_fact:
    dst: "{{ dst + [ item[0] ] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{failed_connections}}"
  vars:
    dst: []
```

I find this makes the expression a little simpler.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get a list of all addresses and preferably only unique ones?

To append the items in the list

```yaml
  dst: "{{ dst + item[0] }}"
```

To get a unique list:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    unique_list: "{{ dst | unique }}"
```

If that doesn't work, [try to look at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983209/ansible-cannot-append-into-a-list-in-a-with-items-loop).

Comment: ty for answer! It helped me like this "{{ dst | default([])  + [item[0]] }}"