# creating dictionary from list in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have following results and I would like to create dictionary form lists. Could you please advise?

Input:

```
  "destination": [
    [
        "URL=http://apps.introext.net/meta.html,checksum=99e2714f6269cbe49fe641ab9f4f84e661334fa4,remotefile=meta.html"
    ],
    [
        "URL=http://apps.introext.net/data.html,checksum=7985e6b97a915ec6681b628c783fa2a52c6f055a,remotefile=data.html"
    ]
]
```

}

Expected Output:

```
{"URL":"http://apps.introext.net/meta.html", "checksum":"99e2714f6269cbe49fe641ab9f4f84e661334fa2","remotefile":"meta.html"}

{"URL":"http://apps.introext.net/data.html","checksum":"7985e6b97a915ec6681b628c788522a52c6f055a","remotefile":"data.html"}
```

Thanks,
Maddy

Comment: Hi Kelson,

This is different from actual link provided. I need to extract values from each sub list.

Answer (score 2):

Well, got this working from it. Try do the following and then read all the posts from that link I sent... It will work as you need.

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        first_list: "{{ first_list | default([]) + [item.split(',')] }}"
      with_items: "{{ destination }}"

    - set_fact:
        final_list: "{{ final_list | default([]) | combine(dict([ item.partition('=')[::2]|map('trim')])) }}"
      with_items: "{{ first_list }}"

    - debug: var=final_list
```

Your output will be something like this:

> ```
> TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************
> ok: [localhost] => {
>     "final_list": {
>         "URL": "http://apps.introext.net/data.html", 
>         "checksum": "7985e6b97a915ec6681b628c783fa2a52c6f055a", 
>         "remotefile": "data.html"
>     }
> }
> ```

Hope this can help you.

Source: [Using Ansible set_fact to create a dictionary from register results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605603/using-ansible-set-fact-to-create-a-dictionary-from-register-results)

Comment: Hi Kelson,

This actually worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution, demonstrating how we can achieve more with Jinja filters.